# Перенаправление обращения к внешнему адресу на внутренний

Tags: linux, маршрутизация

Есть рабочий сервер с готовым проектом на локалке, все работает отлично. но как мне прописать локальный айпи сервера на маршрутизаторе так, чтобы при запросе на внешний (статический айпи) или на домен, было перенаправтение в сервер. Model No. TL-WR840N - модель моего маршрутизатора.

Когда добавляю Static Route, а по маршруту ставлю внешний айпи, все вылетает. к слову порт 80/tcp открыт.

Comment: ищи в админке роутера ключевые слова "virtual servers" или "port forwarding".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> как мне прописать локальный айпи сервера на рутере так чтоб при
> запросе на внешний (статический айпи )или на домен было
> перенаправтение в сервер

Для этого придуман (давным-давно) механизм, называемый NAT - Network Address Translation. Почему "трансляция"? Потому, что он переводит (транслирует) сокет Вашего **локального** сервера (а это - пара IP:Port) в сокет на Вашем роутере, который привязывается к **глобальному** адресу вашего роутера в интернете.

Грубо говоря, пара <ваш IP>:<Ваш порт> превращается в <IP роутера>:<Некий порт на роутере> и роутер, получая от Вас пакет преобразует его по правилам NAT во внешнее представление сокета, а получив пакет из инета, выполняет обратное преобразование и отдаёт полученный пакет Вашему серверу.

Управляется весь этот механизм (изначально)с помощью *iptables*.

Для начала, посмотрите вот это: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT